# How to download SQLite file from server and replace old database file if necessary

Tags: android, sqlite

I have server with SQLite database on it. When app runs, it connects to server and gets a JSON file. In this JSON file I have database update time and link to database file. How can I download this file and replace the old database with this new?

Comment: Since the file is being downloaded at same path.It will  override the already written file..Hence whenever download is being made you are replacing the old file with the new one

Answer (score 0):

```
onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
   switch(oldVersion) {
   case 1:
       db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_color);
       // And download new with database set newVersoin 
   case 2:

   }
}
```